# Approximate merge of matrices in a list

Tags: r

As example, I made two matrix with different dimensions. I want to merge those two lists on nearest [,2] value.
Step 1. Find [,2] of list1 which is nearest to the [,2] of list2
Step 2.  add [,3] list3 next to the corresponding [,2].

```
m1 <- c(1,2,3, 1.1, 3.3, 2.6, 123, 456,786)
dim(m1) <- c(3,3)
m2 <- c(11,22,33, 1.1, 2.6, 3.8, 123, 456,789)
dim(m2) <- c(3,3)
list1 <- list(m1, m2)

m3 <- c(100, 200, 300, 1, 2.4, 3.5, 523, 634, 876)
dim(m3) <- c(3,3)
list2 <- list(m3)
```

The expected out put is:

```
> list[[1]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1  1.1  123  523
[2,]    2  3.3  456  876
[3,]    3  2.6  786  634
> list[[2]]
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]   11  1.1  123  523
[2,]   22  2.6  456  634
[3,]   33  3.8  789  876
```

hopefully my word is clear.

Comment: please rephrase the question.It is not clear as is

Comment: Include the output in your question

Comment: You need to rephrase your question. Seems english is abit difficult, but try to use google translate to enable you ask a coherent question

Answer (score 0):

The fuzzyjoin package can do that sort of matching-merging. It expects arguments of class `tbl`.

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(fuzzyjoin)

lapply( list1, function(x)  
          difference_left_join( as_tibble(x), as_tibble(list2[[1]]), 
                                 by=c(2,2) ,        # merge x.col2 to y.col2 
                                 max_dist=0.5)      # limit distance matched
+ )
[[1]]
# A tibble: 3 × 6
   V1.x  V2.x  V3.x  V1.y  V2.y  V3.y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     1   1.1   123   100   1     523
2     2   3.3   456   300   3.5   876
3     3   2.6   786   200   2.4   634

[[2]]
# A tibble: 3 × 6
   V1.x  V2.x  V3.x  V1.y  V2.y  V3.y
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1    11   1.1   123   100   1     523
2    22   2.6   456   200   2.4   634
3    33   3.8   789   300   3.5   876
```

You may need to fiddle with the max_dist value since leaving it at its default will get you extra rows that don't line up with your specification. Obviously you could drop unwanted columns but I'm leaving them in so you can see the logic better.